# EntityFramework FromRawSql count query

Tags: entity-framework-core

Here is what i've done with entityframework.
I have a very complex query and i wanted to write it as a raw sql query this way:

```
var queryable1 = dbcontext.Set<MyViewModel>().FromSqlRaw(
  " SELECT "
+ " field1,"
+ " field2,"
+ " <calculation1> as field3, 
+ " (select count(*) from ...) as field4, "
...
+ " FROM mytable "
+ " LEFT JOIN xxxx "
+ " WHERE ...");
```

It works fine: I can query this way:

```
var queryable2 = queryable1.Where(....);
```

I have a problem when i try to make a count:

```
var count1 = queryable1.Count();
```

The count result is good but if i look the sql query executed on sql server i can see this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
  (SELECT field1, field2, <calculation1> as field3, ... FROM mytable WHERE ...)
```

This query is very slow. Is there a way to do something like that:

```
  SELECT count(*) FROM mytable WHERE ...
```

Thanks

Comment: Nope, EF just wraps your raw SQL into subquery  and calculates `Count`.

Comment: Do you think this kind of count is slower than a basic count ?

Comment: I do not understand question. EF do not parse raw SQL and just envelope it in subquery. If you think it is slow, provide another raw SQL or LINQ query. Anyway analyze execution plan.

Comment: I can write a custom count rawsql query. But i want a single IQureyable object. On this object i want to iterate on results and i want to call Count(). When iterating i want to call my initial query. And when calling Count() i want to call my custom select count(*) query. Thanks